# Calculation of Cost Amount Physical

Tags: axapta, inventory

How does AX calculate the Cost Amount Physical on inventory transactions (`Inventrans` table)?

When posting packing slip in purchase order, transaction records are created in the Inventrans table, this table has a field (CostAmountPhysical)

How does AX calculate the value of this field?

Sometimes this value is different to the net amount calculated in each item of the purchase order?

Comment: Help us help you - I don't understand this question at all.  More detail and words that aren't acronyms might help.

Answer (score 0):

The `CostAmountPhysical` field is calculated in the `InventMovement.updateLedgerPhysical` method.

There is no easy explanation of how and why it is calculated. Go and have look in the code.

Please update you cross reference, this simplifies questions like this one enormously.